Issue with Hindi in Apache FOP 2 version
I am getting incorrect Hindi text in rendered PDF using Apache FOP 2.0 using different Hindi fonts (Nirmla UI, Arial Unicode, Mangal, Aparaj, Amiko, Kokila fonts). I tried to adding script dev/dev2 also. Still incorrect Hindi text displaying in the PDF.
<fo:block font-family="NirmalaUI" margin-top="0.25in">          
            abc Nirmla Font
            <fo:block> प्राप्त विश्व प्रश्न  के चु   इं   रें   टे  मिटे   है    व्यक्तिगत    हैं     प्राप्त     उक्त   प्लान </fo:block>
            <fo:block margin-top="0.25in" script="deva">deva प्राप्त विश्व प्रश्न  के चु   इं   रें   टे  मिटे   है    व्यक्तिगत    हैं     प्राप्त     उक्त   प्लान </fo:block>
            <fo:block margin-top="0.25in" script="deva2">deva2 प्राप्त विश्व प्रश्न  के चु   इं   रें   टे  मिटे   है    व्यक्तिगत    हैं     प्राप्त     उक्त   प्लान </fo:block>
</fo:block>

I configured the fonts in the config file:
<font kerning="yes" embed-url="fonts\nirmalaui.ttf">
            <font-triplet name="NirmalaUI" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
        </font>
        
        <font kerning="yes" embed-url="fonts\ARIALUNI.ttf">
            <font-triplet name="Arial Unicode" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
        </font>
        
        <font kerning="yes" embed-url="fonts\MANGALB.ttf">
            <font-triplet name="Mangal" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
        </font>
        
        <font kerning="yes" embed-url="fonts\aparaj.ttf">
            <font-triplet name="Aparaj" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
        </font>
        
        <font kerning="yes" embed-url="fonts\Amiko-Regular.ttf">
            <font-triplet name="Amiko" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
        </font>
        
        <font kerning="yes" embed-url="fonts\Kokila.ttf">
            <font-triplet name="Kokila" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
        </font>

Expected Hindi text in the PDF is

But, I am getting the incorrect Hindi text in the PDF

Please help me how to fix it.
